# Django Forms with Foreign Key using Materialize

Tags: python, django-forms, django-queryset, django-widget

#### What I Want

Create the same form that shows on Django admin on templates.

#### The Problem

I cannot load the foreign keys into the forms. I was searching for a solution for two days. I have read the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types) for `ModelForm` and `QuerySet` but I cannot find the solution. If anyone here can help me, it´s gonna be awesome. Thanks for your time!

#### My Code

`models.py`:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Categoria(models.Model):
    categoria = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, verbose_name="Nome da categoria", 
        help_text="colocar aqui o texto de ajuda"
    )
    resumo = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, verbose_name="Resumo",
        help_text="colocar aqui o texto de ajuda"
    )
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=1)

    class Meta:
        # Gives the proper plural name for admin
        verbose_name_plural = "Categorias"
        verbose_name = "categoria"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoria

class Serie(models.Model):
    serie = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        verbose_name="Série",
        help_text="colocar aqui o texto de ajuda"
    )
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(
        Categoria,
        default=1,
        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT
    )
    resumo = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "serie"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.serie

class Artigo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        verbose_name='Título do Post',
        help_text='Procure usar um texto que seja a pergunta de um usuário: Ex. Como escolher o revestimento '
    )
    heading = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        verbose_name='Chamada',
        help_text='Um texto pequeno para atrair o leitor'
    )
    serie = models.ForeignKey(
        Serie,
        default='1',
        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT
    )
    text = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now,
        verbose_name='Data de criação:'
    )
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Data de postagem:'
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='Url única:',
        help_text='A URL deve ser única, representar o conteúdo, e ser chamativa para SEO'
    )
    tags = TaggableManager(verbose_name='tags')

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`forms.py`:

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Artigo, Serie

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Artigo
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input', 'placeholder': 'Digite um texto'}), 
            'heading': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input', 'placeholder': 'Digite um texto'}),  
            'serie': forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Série.objects.all()),  
            'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'input',}),  
            'created_date': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker', 'type':'datetime','placeholder': 'Digite um texto'}),
            'published_date': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker', 'placeholder': 'Digite um texto'}),  
            'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input', 'placeholder': 'Digite um texto'}),
            'tags': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'chips chips-placeholder',}),
        }`
```

#### Some Posts in StackOverflow that I have Read:

- [Django forms and querysets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008420/django-forms-and-querysets)
- [Django ModelForm with foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164798/django-modelform-with-foreign-key)
- [Django Queryset foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067851/django-queryset-foreign-keys)
- [MultiValueField does not work with ModelChoiceField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362074/multivaluefield-does-not-work-with-modelchoicefield)
- [Multi select input in admin site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848324/multi-select-input-in-admin-site)

Best regards,

A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found a solution.

You have to be careful when using Django and Materialize at the same time.

Material CSS is set to work with some **classes** and some of them **need JavaScript to work correctly**.

Forms in Django are rendered in different classes, and you need to init jQuery using IDs instead of classes.

#### To check what happens:

1. Remove all CSS and reference of style (use raw HTML)
2. If the `form` is rendered, your problem is not on the foreign keys

#### Code example:

Using this code on the template that renders the `forms.py`, I was able to find the solution

```html
<script>
  // datepicker for 
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_published_date, #id_created_date').datepicker();
  });
  // Select 
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').formSelect();
  });
</script>
```